# Need to make an asp.net site that authenticates on behalf of the user in another Active Directory Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, forward

I need to make an asp.net C# website where the user signs on the site, the site then logs into an active directory server and checks the users group, depending on group it forwards the user to one of 2 url's. At those urls is the real active directory login page setup for the group there in, but the asp site should log the user in on there behalf so the user shouldn't see that login page and should be skipped directly to the "logged in" page.

The asp page I'm making has already done everything except the part where it logs in the user on their behalf. As of now the user is taken to the correct site but is faced with another login page so he/she will have to end up logging in twice basically.

Both are on completely different servers, however, the asp.net site is in the local domain of the active directory server so it can still authenticate and access the server despite the fact that it's outside the servers network. So far I'm successfully using LDAP to test authenticate the user and get the users groups but like I said it doesn't carry over the authentication to the forwarded URL so the user will have to end up logging in again.

I have to note that this is for a company I work for so much of the code and details are private. I was only allowed to post this much.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of .NET you were using.  If it's 4.5, then if it were me, I'd get my infrastructure guys to put ADFS in.  The user would log into ADFS which would pass a token to the first site.  When the user was forwarded to either of the second sites, it would redirect to ADFS for its token, but since the user would already have authenticated to ADFS, the token would be issued without the user having to do anything else.

If you're using .Net 4.0, it's as easy but they baked all of the Claims stuff into the core of 4.5 whereas it's bolted onto .Net 4.0.  There's a couple of courses on PluralSight, by Dominick Baier, which will get you up to speed in a few hours.  They are well worth the month's subscription.